# Python acting in a strange way (Dynamic Programing)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have written this following code that takes an integer **N** and and array of integers: **arr**. The task is to find the shortest combination of the integers in arr that sum up to **N** . Each elements of **arr** can be used as times as you want. For example **9, [3,2]** should produce the result **[3,3,3]** instead of **[2,2,2,3]** as the former combination is of shorter length( lesser number of elements).

```
def bestSum(n, arr, memo={}):
    key=str(n)
    if key in memo.keys():
        return memo[key]
    if n<0 :
        return None
    if n==0:
        return []

    best_solution = None
    for i in arr:
        solution= bestSum(n-i,arr,memo)
        if (solution is not None):
            combination = list(k for k in solution)
            combination.append(i)
            if((best_solution is None ) or (len(combination)<len(best_solution))):
                best_solution=combination
    memo[key] =best_solution
    return best_solution



print(bestSum(8,[3,2]))
print(bestSum(8, [4,2]))
```

The output of first print statement is **[2,3,3]** which is correct.
But the second print statement also produced **[2, 3, 3]** which is not possible as there is no **3** in arr in this case. The output should have been **[4,4]**

Now if I remove 1st statement and execute only the second statement, then It produces correct result => **[4,4]**

Again, if I change the order like-

```
print(bestSum(8, [4,2]))
print(bestSum(8,[3,2]))
```

both these two produces **[4,4]**

It seems as if the **memo** created in  `print(bestSum(8, [4,2]))` is existing even after completion of returning the value to first **print** and the second call  `print(bestSum(8, [3,2]))` is using the same **memo**.

I can't understand why is it happening so? shouldn't the first **memo** object be automatically erased after completion of first **print** ? Shouldn't a new **memo** be created in the second call?

If **memo** continues to exist after completion of 1st statement it should be able to be accessed outside of that statement like
`print(memo)`
But this is not the case

Comment: You are correct, the dictionary `memo` is a mutable default argument to the `bestSum()` function. It is shared among all calls to the function, even the second call, separate one, i.e. `print(bestSum(8, [4,2]))`


You might wanna initialize the default argument in the following way:

```
def bestSum(n, arr, memo=None):
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
\\... rest of the logic
```

Tested it, seems to work for the two inputs you provided.

Comment: Thank You so much, Learnt a new fact !!! Is it true for python only ? In JavaScript the same code works just fine even with a mutable default argument ( a JavaScript Object).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, default arguments are evaluated when the function is defined, not each time the function is called. This means that if you use a mutable default argument and mutate it, the mutated object will be used whenever the function is called.

So in your function, `memo={}` is only evaluated once, when the function is defined. That's why when you call `bestSum` the second time, it uses the same `memo` dictionary from the first call, not a new empty dictionary. This is why the second call is returning the incorrect result, because it is utilizing the `memo` from the first call.

A common Python idiom to avoid this issue is to use `None` as the default argument value, and then set the actual default value inside the function. Here's how you could modify your function:

```py
def bestSum(n, arr, memo=None):
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
    key=str(n)
    if key in memo.keys():
        return memo[key]
    if n<0 :
        return None
    if n==0:
        return []

    best_solution = None
    for i in arr:
        solution= bestSum(n-i,arr,memo)
        if (solution is not None):
            combination = list(k for k in solution)
            combination.append(i)
            if((best_solution is None ) or (len(combination)<len(best_solution))):
                best_solution=combination
    memo[key] =best_solution
    return best_solution
```

With this change, every time `bestSum` is called, `memo` will be a new empty dictionary if no other value is provided, so you won't have issues with data from previous calls affecting your results.

---

With that being said, here is an attempt to rewrite your solution to be slightly more Pythonic:

```
from typing import Optional


def best_sum(target: int,
             nums: list[int],
             memo: Optional[dict[int, int]] = None) -> Optional[list[int]]:
  """
  Function to find the shortest combination of integers that sums up to target. 
  Each number in the nums list can be used an unlimited number of times. 

  Args:
      target: The target sum.
      nums: List of integers available.
      memo: Memoization dictionary. Defaults to None.

  Returns:
      Optional[list[int]]: The shortest combination of integers from nums 
                            that sum up to target. If no combination is 
                            possible, return None.
  """
  if memo is None:
    memo = {}
  if target < 0:
    return None
  if target == 0:
    return []
  if target in memo:
    return memo[target]
  best_solution = None
  for num in nums:
    remainder = target - num
    remainder_combination = best_sum(remainder, nums, memo)
    if remainder_combination is not None:
      combination = remainder_combination + [num]
      if best_solution is None or len(combination) < len(best_solution):
        best_solution = combination
  memo[target] = best_solution
  return best_solution

print(best_sum(8, [3, 2]))  # [2, 3, 3]
print(best_sum(8, [4, 2]))  # [4, 4]
```

Comment: I spent a day trying to figure this out. THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!!!!

Comment: I have one more doubt-  "Is it true for python only? In JavaScript the same code with the use of a default mutable argument seems to work fine"

Comment: The behavior of default arguments in Python is different from JavaScript.

In JavaScript, parameters are always passed by value, and every time a function is called, a new execution context is created, so a new instance of the default argument object is created. This means that changes to the object inside the function do not persist across function calls, which is different from Python.